# Can't set InkToolbarRulerButton background as transparent using InkToolbar

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml, inkcanvas

I create a ink toolbar, and the initial controls are all except pens.
I can set the eraser button's background as transparent, but apply to the ruler button.
Is this a ink toolbar bug?

```
<InkToolbar Background="Transparent" InitialControls="AllExceptPens" TargetInkCanvas="{x:Bind inkCanvas}">
      <InkToolbarEraserButton Background="Transparent"/>
      <InkToolbarRulerButton Background="Transparent"/>
</InkToolbar>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule button is actually  the `InkToolbarStencilButton` in the visual tree, not `InkToolbarRulerButton`. So that update your code snippet as follows will work.

```
<InkToolbar
    Background="Transparent"
    InitialControls="AllExceptPens" 
    <InkToolbarEraserButton Background="Red" />
    <!--<InkToolbarRulerButton Background="Red" Foreground="Blue"   />-->
    <InkToolbarStencilButton Background="Red"></InkToolbarStencilButton>
</InkToolbar>
```